# Using Ajax CORS IE 11 in IE 5 Document Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am in quite an interesting situation. I work for a middle sized company and we have IE 11 for our browser but for a particular application I am programming, its document mode is set to IE 5. I am making calls to a web service located within the company Intranet (the particular URL is https) and the website where I'm making the call is http (not sure if I can set document.domain or anything here). I am currently using ajax and I'm able to successfully communicate with service and get code back using the code below. Although, each time I do get the message that says, "the information you're accessing is coming from another source." If I hit yes, then I get information back from the server, if I hit no, then the data does not come through. I tried to call this same method from a different page on the same website, and instead get the access denied error, without even having the prompt. That one really has me confused.

I've read through many many different articles on the subject of CORS at this point and know there's a few things to try to avoid this message. Credentials are omitted below. I am using Jquery 1.9.1 minimized version.

```
    $.support.cors = true;

            $.ajax
            ({
               type: "POST",
               crossDomain: true,
               beforeSend: function(request)
               {
                   request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "");
                   return true;
               },
               url: webServiceURL,
               dataType: "xml",
               async: true,
               data: soapMessage, 
               contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
               success: OnSuccess, 
               error: OnError
});


}

function OnSuccess(data, status)
    {

        alert(status);
        alert(data);

        var documentValArr = parseXMLRrec(data);
        insertDataIntoTable(documentValArr);

    }

    function OnError(request, status, error)
    {

        alert(request.responseText);
        alert(error);
        alert(status);
    }
```

1. Enable cross domain sources IE setting. I suppose this can try to be set for that specific URL in that intranet zone, but it still feels wrong to me. Not sure how the security group at work would feel about it either.
2. Add the URL I'm trying to access to the Intranet trusted sites. I think this would fix the issue I'm seeing and this is something I definitely would want to try.
3. Also, when testing on my local workstation and calling the web service through IE 11 doc 5 mode, I do not get the message.
4. Work with the group that owns the server where the service lives, and see if they can somehow add URL's that can access the service alright. This would be interesting because there are quite a lot of production sites.
5. Because I'm using IE 11 in doc 5 mode I could try to use the XDomainRequest object but I am not sure if it would be a worth while effort to do this if the earlier options work out.

So there my interesting scenario is. I would very much like some feed back from people on the situation, what they would do, and what type of things and solutions go for. THank you very much for all input and ideas!

Comment: I don't think this can be solved without creating a proxy between app A and app B, or using JSONP. CORS support doesn't exist in IE7 (which document mode 5, or, quirks mode, is based on)